# Contact Form 7 - Don't show blank text fields in email

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I have a lot of fields in my contact form and I would like the blank fields not to be displayed in the email received.

Is there a way to do this by adding php code in the message body (wordpress > admin > contact form)? Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Contact Form 7 in Wordpress - How can I hide incompleted fields in the e-mail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007502/contact-form-7-in-wordpress-how-can-i-hide-incompleted-fields-in-the-e-mail)

Answer (score 8):

Simply check the checkbox parallel to the text "Exclude lines with blank mail-tags from output", under the message body field in your wp-admin contact form 7.

Answer (score 1):

Here is info on how to accomplish this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-how-to-do-away-with-blank-lines-in-email-for-unfilled-form-items

You need to add a few lines of code to your functions.php file.