# Contact Form 7 in Wordpress - How can I hide empty fields in the e-mail?

Tags: wordpress, email, field, contact-form, contact-form-7

this question is similar with my question but this doesn't have problem solving answer 
[Contact Form 7 in Wordpress - How can I hide incompleted fields in the e-mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007502/contact-form-7-in-wordpress-how-can-i-hide-incompleted-fields-in-the-e-mail)

I just want to remove that rows from email where value is not given

Answer (score 0):

IF if you have single form, or multiple ones with similar field sets, you can leave `Message body` blank in contact form settings, and add this function to functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'add_extra_details', 50, 2 );
function add_extra_details($mail_params, $form = null) {
    $fields = $_POST;
    $keys_to_include = array(
        'your-name' => 'Name',
        'your-email' => 'Email',
        'your-subject' => 'Subject'
    );

    foreach ($fields as $k => $v) {

        if (array_key_exists($k, $keys_to_include)) {
            $mail_params['body'] .= '<br />'.$keys_to_include[$k].': '.$v;
        }
    }

    return $mail_params;
}
```

Just map `$keys_to_include` according to you fields in form, if you want to do this only to certain form, you can wrap everything in condition to check form id first (contact form has lot of hidden fields use them)

Comment: thanks for your time.
I solved this problem using other method